# reCaptcha V2 slow loading or not loading at all

Tags: recaptcha

I have several forms on my website that all uses reCaptcha V2. When the form is opened the reCAPTCHA logo/checkbox is not visible but loads minutes later.          I have same problem on google chrome and Edge chromium.

For some clients reCAPTCHA doesn’t appear at all and we are getting complaints because the form will not submit.

Any help on this matter please

I have verified the keys are correct. I have re-committed the keys in the form builder and reset the reCaptcha details in each form settings.
I am using 'super forms' form builder.